# Attribute error while using methods from linked libraries in python

Tags: c++, python, ctypes, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to use some C++ method in my python code and I'm using `ctypes` library. I have wrote a simple C++ code using a simple `main` with no arguments and another simple method named `printArgs` which takes an argument of type `char *`. I also have wrote a simple python code to import these two methods. I made two linked libraries(one `.so` and one `.a` because I'm using Debian) with this command:

```
g++ -o hello.so -shared -fPIC hello.cpp
```

And then used `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/the/path/to/the/linked/libraries/directory`.

There is no problem in getting the `main` method, bu when I'm trying to get `printArgs` I get `AttributeError`. Here's the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int printArgs(char * args_array){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout<<i<<"- "<<args_array[i]<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the Python code:

```
from ctypes import *
helloInCPP_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("hello.a")
print helloInCPP_lib
helloInCPPMain = helloInCPP_lib.main
print helloInCPPMain
helloInCPPPrint = helloInCPP_lib.printArgs
print helloInCPPPrint
```

I get this output:

```
<CDLL 'hello.a', handle 9c45488 at b73d1e6c>
<_FuncPtr object at 0xb73e67e4>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "testHelloInCPP.py", line 9, in <module>
        helloInCPPPrint = helloInCPP_lib.printArgs(None)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
        func = self.__getitem__(name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__
        func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /etc/linked_libraries/hello.a: undefined symbol: printArgs
```

I also tried `cdll.LoadLibrary("hello.so")` and/or `helloInCPPPrint = helloInCPP_lib.printArgs(None)`; got the same error in both conditions. Any idea?

I'm using Debian 32 bit on a VMWare Workstation and Python 2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the `printArgs` using [`extern "C"`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    int printArgs(char * args_array);
}

int printArgs(char * args_array){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout<<i<<"- "<<args_array[i]<<"\n";
    }
}

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello\n";
}
```

---

BTW, you should pass a string (c_char_p), not `None`:

```
...
helloInCPPPrint = helloInCPP_lib.printArgs
helloInCPPPrint.argtypes = [c_char_p]
print helloInCPPPrint("ABCDE")
```

About `argtypes`, see [Specifying the required argument types (function prototypes)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes).

Comment: I have got `Segmentation fault` for `printArgs`.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi, What did you pass to `printArg` ? `None` ??

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi, I updated the answer with slightly modified Python code. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer.

Comment: BTW I changed the `printArgs` to a `void` method and removed `return 0;`; it works fine but it prints out `-1222451712` at the end. What is it exactly?

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi, See [`restype`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.restype)  and [Return types](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types).

Comment: Thank you; it seems I should learn more and more about the `ctypes` library.

Answer (score 0):

I tired compiling the solution by @falsetru using

```
g++ -O3 -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC code.cpp -o lib.so
```

but could not without this small modification to code.c, according to the link provided in their answer [extern "C"](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int printArgs(char * args_array){
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout<<i<<"- "<<args_array[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
```